# C pointers-What is the solution of Segment fault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, swap

Why does it output "Segmentation fault(core dumped)

When I run the following code it says Segment fault(core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *, int *);

int main() {
    int x = 5, y = 10;
    swap(x, y);
    printf("%i\n %i\n", x, y);
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int s;
    s = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = s;
}
```

Comment: Call to `swap()` - in `main()` - is incorrect. It should be `swap(&x, &y)`

Comment: You should get a compiler warning on this line: `swap(x,y);`. Compile with `-Wall`. And BTW what would `swap(3,4);` do? And also put some effort in formatting your code.

Comment: You are passing the value of variables `x` and `y` , *not*  their addresses.

Comment: Please ___properly___ indent your code. Machine (Compiler) can read and compile anything, but for humans, it needs to make a little _sense_ while reading a block of text as _code_. When asking question, there was a big orange __How to Format__ box to the right of the text area. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a __[?]__ button giving formatting help. And a preview area  showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: The problem is that you are using a trash compiler. This code is not allowed to compile without a warning/error from the compiler.

Comment: As others have mentioned, you should have seen compiler warnings. If not, turn them on and do not ignore them. Warnings are often errors waiting to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in line `swap(x, y);`

You are passing the values and not the addresses. You should have got compiler warnings.

Use `swap(&x, &y);`